# Android Kotlin + Retrofit + Hlt + MVVM change dynamic url runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, dagger-hilt

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit{
        //val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()

        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val httpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        httpBuilder
            //.dispatcher(dispatcher)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)  /// show all JSON in logCat
        val mClient = httpBuilder.build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            //.addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(mClient)
            .build()
    }


    @Provides
    fun provideHTTPLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        return interceptor
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .callTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesSalesAPI(retrofit: Retrofit): SalesApi {
        return retrofit.create(SalesApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

how i can change BASE_URL on any button click ?
I have used MVVM repository pattern and have not been able to change URL runtime.
please help me with what i have to change in example above.
NOTE : The URL will change if i restart the application but I want change URL without app restart

Comment: Can't we use ```@Url``` annotation ? https://www.baeldung.com/retrofit-dynamic-url

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best solution or not, but you can create two `Retrofit` instances with the two `BASE_URL`s:

```kotlin
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class RetrofitOne

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class RetrofitTwo

@Provides
@Singleton
@RetrofitOne
fun providesRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient):
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_1)
            ...

@Provides
@Singleton
@RetrofitTwo
fun providesRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient):
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_2)
            ...

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesSalesAPI(@RetrofitOne retrofit: Retrofit): SalesApi {
    return retrofit.create(SalesApi::class.java)
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesAnotherSalesAPI(@RetrofitTwo retrofit: Retrofit): SalesApi {
    return retrofit.create(SalesApi::class.java)
}
```

Comment: but I have no of multiple URLs which can be changed on the button click

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/change-retrofit-base-url-on-runtime-2036ef1dee44

interceptor will help you here